# TinyMce and Responsive Filemanager set up

Tags: javascript, tinymce, file-management, responsive-filemanager

Ok, So I am trying to set up Responsive Filemanager in TinyMce but I am not able to get it to work.
My directory set up is:C:\wamp\www\tinymce\webbsite

```
webbsite
-filemanager
--config
---config.php
--plugin.min.js
-js
--tinymce
---plugins
---tinymce.min.jc
-source
-thumbs
-tinymce
```

The javascript script:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",theme: "modern",width: 680,height: 300,
        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
             "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
        ],
        toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
        toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",

image_advtab: true,
external_filemanager_path:"C:/wamp/www/tinymce/webbsite/filemanager/",
filemanager_title:"Responsive Penisemanager" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "C:/wamp/www/tinymce/webbsite/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",theme: "modern",width: 680,height: 300,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
    toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",

    image_advtab: true,
    external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
    filemanager_title:"Responsive Penisemanager",
    external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
});
```

And in your directory:

```
webbsite
-filemanager
--config
---config.php
--plugin.min.js
-js
-source
-thumbs
-tinymce
--plugins
---responsivefilemanager
----plugin.min.js
--tinymce.min.jc
```